# How to run mscomm32.ocx under Windows 7?

Tags: replace, serial-port, windows-7-x64, mscomm32

We get an app that was working fine until update Windows from Vista Home Basic to 7 Home Premium. We use mscomm32.ocx to control serial port, but it seems it's not supported for 64 bits OS.

Each time we try to read the port: Thisform.msCommControl.Input We got the following:

> OLE IDispath exception code 0 from MSComm: Error reading comm devide

We've made a lot of unsuccessful tests. Does any one know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you also change from a 32 bit OS to a 64 bit OS at the same time?  Is your program 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use an updated control that is contantly under development so newer Windows are also supported. [ADONTEC's SuperCom ActiveX](http://adontec.com/scocx_e.htm) is a MSComm compatible ActiveX that developers use for many years in order to replace the MSComm. It is compatible with 32 and 64 bit of Windows 2000/XP/7/8 and Windows 10. You are almost done in few minutes. In many cases the application runs not only faster but is by far more stable and it also offers by far more functionality. See more info [here](http://adontec.com/scocx_faq_mscomm.htm).

Answer (score 0):

that MSCOMM32.OCX will not work with Windows 7 64 bit machines. However, strange as it may seem I have a VB6 program controlling equipment from a virtual comm port (USB ~ serial converter)
It works fine on windows 8.64 bit machine.
The only thing is that the converter driver had to be modified to run on 64 bit.
If you are using a real com port that doesn't matter.
Try it on a 64 bit machine with Windows 8